# Integration involving bivariate normal

Tags: r, integration

I am doing single integration in R with the following code:

```
MU <- c(1,3)
Sigma <- matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,1.5),2,2)
y0 <- 3
integrate(function(xx,MU,Sigma,y0)  {
  dnorm(xx,mean=MU[1],sd=Sigma[1,1])*pmvnorm(lower=c
  (-Inf,-Inf),upper=c(xx,y0),mean=MU,sigma=Sigma)}, 
  y0=y0, MU=MU,Sigma=Sigma, lower=-Inf, upper=Inf,subdivisions=1000)
```

but I got the error message:

> Error in checkmvArgs(lower = lower, upper = upper, mean = mean, corr =
>   corr,  : 
>       ‘diag(sigma)’ and ‘lower’ are of different length.

I have searched for clues and some mentioned about vectorizing the integrant to make the wrapper function. But I'm not sure how to proceed and why it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to vectorize the integrand.

```
MU <- c(1, 3)
Sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1.5), 2, 2)
y0 <- 3
integrate(
  Vectorize(function(xx, MU, Sigma, y0)  {
    dnorm(xx, mean = MU[1], sd = Sigma[1, 1]) * pmvnorm(
      lower = c(-Inf, -Inf),
      upper = c(xx, y0),
      mean = MU,
      sigma = Sigma
    )
  }, vectorize.args = "xx"),
  y0 = y0,
  MU = MU,
  Sigma = Sigma,
  lower = -Inf,
  upper = Inf,
  subdivisions = 1000
)
```

Result:

```
0.2966074 with absolute error < 7e-06
```